# ¿Cómo definir el tamaño de hoja en reportlab?

Tags: python, reportlab

Quisiera saber cómo puedo definir el tamaño de una hoja, que sea en Carta, hasta ahorita solo vi que la librería para usar es esta:

```
 from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import
```

Pero si alguien podría darme mas información de cómo aplicarlo, se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues, sí. Dentro de `reportlab.lib.pagesizes` hay muchos tamaños predefinidos. Para tamaño carta tendrías que usar `letter`:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


ancho, alto = letter
c = canvas.Canvas('prueba.pdf')
c.setPageSize((ancho, alto))
```

Lo he hecho de esa forma para que notes que `letter` no es más que una tupla con las medidas para ese tamaño específico.

```
>>> from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
>>> letter
(612.0, 792.0)
```

Podrías simplemente hacer:

```
c.setPageSize(letter)
```

También es posible pasar tu propio ancho y alto. Por ejemplo, en pulgadas:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch


c = canvas.Canvas('prueba.pdf')
c.setPageSize((5*inch, 8*inch))
```

Comment: ooh waaaooo gracias muchas gracias en serio gracias :)

Comment: la forma en la que me diste tu respuesta es muy entendible gracias